# What is the name of the function, which does the opposite to HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode?

Tags: c#, .net, escaping

I need to evaluate escape sequences on the string.
To escape the string, HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode or something similar was used.
How do I do the opposite transformation?

Here's an example:

```
        var s = @"otehu""oeuhnoa
        oaehu
        oatehu
        oeu";
        var t = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(s);
        var n = Decode(t);
```

i need such function Decode, which would make n == s;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this function posted on another forum:

```
public static string JavaScriptStringDecode(string source)
{
    // Replace some chars.
    var decoded = source.Replace(@"\'", "'")
                .Replace(@"\""", @"""")
                .Replace(@"\/", "/")
                .Replace(@"\\", @"\")
                .Replace(@"\t", "\t")
                .Replace(@"\n", "\n");

    // Replace unicode escaped text.
    var rx = new Regex(@"\\[uU]([0-9A-F]{4})");

    decoded = rx.Replace(decoded, match => ((char)Int32.Parse(match.Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber))
                                            .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    return decoded;
}
```

And it worked for me

Comment: This code does some double decoding with `.Replace(@"\\", @"\").Replace(@"\t", "\t").Replace(@"\n", "\n")` which is probably not what most want.

Comment: I'll note that argaz's concern cannot be corrected by reordering the replace calls.  The issue is that `@"\\\\n"` and `@"\\\n"` need to both work, but only one should have a newline.

Answer (score 4):

here is my implementation, for those who are looking for it

```
private string JavaScriptStringDecode(string value, bool removeDoubleQuotes)
            {
                StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
                int startIndex = 0;
                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
                {
                    var c = value[i];
                    if (c == '\\')
                    {
                        if (count > 0)
                        {
                            b.Append(value, startIndex, count);
                            count = 0;
                        }

                        if (i < value.Length - 1)
                        {
                            var c1 = value[i + 1];
                            bool ignore = false;
                            char charToAppend;
                            switch (c1)
                            {
                                case 'r':
                                    charToAppend = '\r';
                                    break;
                                case 't':
                                    charToAppend = '\t';
                                    break;
                                case 'n':
                                    charToAppend = '\n';
                                    break;
                                case 'b':
                                    charToAppend = '\b';
                                    break;
                                case 'f':
                                    charToAppend = '\f';
                                    break;
                                case '\\':
                                    charToAppend = '\\';
                                    break;
                                case '\'':
                                    charToAppend = '\'';
                                    break;
                                case '\"':
                                    charToAppend = '\"';
                                    break;
                                case 'u':
                                case 'U':
                                    if (i < value.Length - 5)
                                    {
                                        var style = NumberStyles.HexNumber;
                                        var cult = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                                        int u;

                                        if (Int32.TryParse(value.Substring(i + 2, 4), style, cult, out u))
                                        {
                                            charToAppend = ((char)u);
                                            i += 4;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    charToAppend = '\\';
                                    ignore = true;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    charToAppend = '\\';
                                    ignore = true;

                                    break;
                            }
                            if (!ignore)
                            {
                                i++;
                            }
                            startIndex = i + 1;
                            b.Append(charToAppend);
                            continue;
                        }


                    }
                    count++;

                }
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    b.Append(value, startIndex, count);
                }
                if (removeDoubleQuotes)
                {
                    if (b.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (b[0] == '"')
                        {
                            b.Remove(0, 1);
                        }
                        if (b[b.Length - 1] == '"')
                        {
                            b.Remove(b.Length - 1, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return b.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: This code missing handling of ASCII encoded characters with \x but it's easy to add.

Comment: There is also an `\x{XXXX}` syntax have to add.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my full implementation that based on @GDocal's code and [String - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences) documentation.

```
private string JavaScriptStringDecode(string value, bool removeDoubleQuotes)
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    int startIndex = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = value[i];
        if (c == '\\')
        {
            if (count > 0)
            {
                b.Append(value, startIndex, count);
                count = 0;
            }

            if (i < value.Length - 1)
            {
                var c1 = value[i + 1];
                bool ignore = false;
                char charToAppend;

                var style = NumberStyles.HexNumber;
                var cult = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                int u;

                switch (c1)
                {
                    case '\'':
                        charToAppend = '\'';
                        break;
                    case '\"':
                        charToAppend = '\"';
                        break;
                    case '\\':
                        charToAppend = '\\';
                        break;
                    case 'n':
                        charToAppend = '\n';
                        break;
                    case 'r':
                        charToAppend = '\r';
                        break;
                    case 'v':
                        charToAppend = '\v';
                        break;
                    case 't':
                        charToAppend = '\t';
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        charToAppend = '\b';
                        break;
                    case 'f':
                        charToAppend = '\f';
                        break;
                    case 'u':
                        if (value[i + 2] == '{')
                        {
                            if (value[i + 4] == '}' && Int32.TryParse(value.Substring(i + 3, 1), style, cult, out u))
                            {
                                charToAppend = ((char)u);
                                i += 5;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (value[i + 5] == '}' && Int32.TryParse(value.Substring(i + 3, 2), style, cult, out u))
                            {
                                charToAppend = ((char)u);
                                i += 6;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (value[i + 6] == '}' && Int32.TryParse(value.Substring(i + 3, 3), style, cult, out u))
                            {
                                charToAppend = ((char)u);
                                i += 7;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (value[i + 7] == '}' && Int32.TryParse(value.Substring(i + 3, 4), style, cult, out u))
                            {
                                charToAppend = ((char)u);
                                i += 8;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (value[i + 8] == '}' && Int32.TryParse(value.Substring(i + 3, 5), style, cult, out u))
                            {
                                charToAppend = ((char)u);
                                i += 9;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (value[i + 9] == '}' && Int32.TryParse(value.Substring(i + 3, 6), style, cult, out u))
                            {
                                charToAppend = ((char)u);
                                i += 10;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Syntax Error
                                throw new FormatException(@"The Unicode code point should be \u{X} ~ \u{XXXXXX}.");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i < value.Length - 5)
                            {
                                if (Int32.TryParse(value.Substring(i + 2, 4), style, cult, out u))
                                {
                                    charToAppend = ((char)u);
                                    i += 4;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        charToAppend = '\\';
                        ignore = true;
                        break;
                    case 'x':
                        if (i < value.Length - 3)
                        {
                            if (Int32.TryParse(value.Substring(i + 2, 2), style, cult, out u))
                            {
                                charToAppend = ((char)u);
                                i += 2;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        charToAppend = '\\';
                        ignore = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        charToAppend = '\\';
                        ignore = true;

                        break;
                }
                if (!ignore)
                {
                    i++;
                }
                startIndex = i + 1;
                b.Append(charToAppend);
                continue;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        b.Append(value, startIndex, count);
    }
    if (removeDoubleQuotes)
    {
        if (b.Length > 0)
        {
            if (b[0] == '"')
            {
                b.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            if (b[b.Length - 1] == '"')
            {
                b.Remove(b.Length - 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return b.ToString();
}
```